# Ruled Text in Textbox with Lines

Tags: textbox, latex, rules

I'd like to have a function for a "letter". By letter I mean that it is a ruled paper, and the text looks justified, as if it would be without the "uline" function.

Moreover, the ulem package is not what I want, since the last line will always be short (any line that has a linebreak).

I am more thinking of something as in the exam class, the \fillwithlines order.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,twoside, DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[papersize={12.5cm,19cm},inner=10mm, outer=10mm, bottom=13mm, top=10mm, footskip=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[]{lipsum}

 \usepackage{xcolor} 
\xdefinecolor{notiz}{RGB}{239,227,157}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\post}[1]{
                         \small
                          \begin{center}

                                \begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
                                    decorate,
                                    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
                                    } %
                                ]
                                \node[ preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,% zeilenabstand=2.8,
                                          transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
                                          pencildraw,draw,fill=notiz,text width=.8\textwidth,
                                          inner sep=5mm] {\uline{#1}};
                                \end{tikzpicture} 

                          \end{center}
                          \normalsize
}

\begin{document}

\post{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```